# docker-compose for JFrog artifactory OSS version?

Tags: docker-compose, artifactory

I want to try out JFrog artifactory OSS using docker compose. I have found:

https://jfrog.com/download-jfrog-platform/

https://api.bintray.com/content/jfrog/artifactory-pro/org/artifactory/pro/docker/jfrog-artifactory-pro/$latest/jfrog-artifactory-pro-$latest-compose.tar.gz;bt_package=jfrog-artifactory-pro

But it seems its only for the PRO/Paid version.

I have found an old/deprecated OSS docker-compose file here:

https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-docker-examples/blob/master/docker-compose/artifactory/artifactory-oss.yml

Does JFrog no longer support OSS when it comes to docker-compose installations?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this today (14.06.2021), it seems like they have moved it over to this website: https://jfrog.com/open-source/#artifactory

You can find the compose download under "linux installers" and in the dropdown menu there should be a "Docker compose" option.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
https://bintray.com/jfrog/product/JFrog-Artifactory-Oss/view

You are able to download the file [jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.11.5-compose.tar.gz](https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory/download_file?file_path=org%2Fartifactory%2Foss%2Fdocker%2Fjfrog-artifactory-oss%2F7.11.5%2Fjfrog-artifactory-oss-7.11.5-compose.tar.gz)

Other OpenSource products are listed here: https://jfrog.com/open-source/

Answer (score 0):

It is really not worth trying to install the OSS version. The PUT and POST api calls are all disabled. And the worst part is that JFrog is not really open about what features are working in the OSS version. It is probably better to look for an alternative solution and leave jfrog/artifactory behind.